# How can I decode these weird characters to readable Persian in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, persian

I'm using sql server to manage a .mdf database. The database content is supposed to be Persian. However what I get is only some weird characters. I've changed every windows setting related to language to Persian and still have the problem. Here you can see a screenshot of what a table looks like

[image]

Do I need a decoding algorithm or I'm just missing a basic configuration?

Comment: Is it converted from the old DOS foxpro DB's? If yes, it's `IranSystem` encoding and it needs to be converted to Unicode first.

Comment: I guess so. It is a database from an old software I've been using. I want to get customized reports not viable through the ui. I'm not an expert though. Can you explain how can it be done in windows? changing IranSystem to Unicode?

Comment: This project is designed to address this issue: https://github.com/mohsen-d/IranSystemConvertor

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot looks like Sql Server Management Studio.

There is `Extras - Options - Environment` where you can select language and proper font.

But - in general - I would avoid languages depending on special characters for technical names.

I have no experience with this, but (just by feeling) I'd assume, that a database with persian object names will be a never ending source of troubles in future...

Persian content in `NVARCHAR` columns shouldn't be a problem though...